# how to use OriginateAction class in asterisk java to originate a call to a PSTN number

Tags: agi

I am new to asterisk, I am trying to originate a call from java application. I found OriginateAction is the class to originate a call to SIP or PSTN number, I tried to use this class but could not find any way how it helps me. Can any one suggest me how to use this class in order to meet my requirement.

I tried following

```
OriginateAction oa=new OriginateAction();
oa.setAccount(getName());
oa.setActionId(getName());
oa.setChannel("SIP/1000");
oa.setContext("default");
oa.setExten("120");
oa.setCallerId("2233");
```

Answer (score 1):

the concept is that: You need to login via ami, then send the action, the minimum infomation you should send is channel(just the sip account like SIP/1000), context, extension, and priority, when you send the action, asterisk will try to call SIP/1000, if the peer answer the call the extension in the context will be called, the, you can do every thing.
maybe this will help I think:
[asterisk manager dialout](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+dialout)
, [java example](https://blogs.reucon.com/asterisk-java/outbound-message-delivery-using-agi-and-ami-in-scala-556/)